# Search for a string in a string (but ignore capitals)

Tags: php

I want to saerch for a special string in a string but the script should ignore capitals.

**Example code:**

```
if (in_string($string, "stringINaSTRING")) {
    echo "The String is in the string!";
}
```

If `$string` contains `STRINGINASCTRING` it should echo `The String is in the string`.

How can I get this done?

Comment: Or convert each string to lowercase and then compare.

Comment: If you got that `in_string` function from the http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php page there is an option for case sensitivity. `function in_string($needle, $haystack, $insensitive = false)`

Answer (score 2):

Use a case insensitive search like [stripos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)

```
if (stripos($string, "STRINGINASTRING"))
{
    echo "The String is in the string!";
}
```

Comment: strpos() would be faster.

Comment: @devlincarnate I doubt `strpos()` would be faster because you'd have to call `strtolower()` on your search string. However `stripos()` is definitely faster.

Comment: ah, ok, you're right.  slightly faster, but faster is faster:  http://www.spudsdesign.com/index.php?t=strpos6

Comment: @devlincarnate Wow that's a lot closer than I was expecting. I ran it a few more times and it went back and forth in which one came out faster. I bet `stripos()` is doing something similar to `strpos()/strtolower()` under the hood

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I've accomplished this (in all sorts of different languages) by converting your string variable to upper or lower case and comparing against an uppercase or lowercase string literal.  That is to say:

```
if (strpos(strtoupper($string), "STRINGINASTRING") !== false) {
    echo "The String is in the string!";
}
```

Also, note the use of the `strpos` function instead of your `in_string` declaration.

This methodology only calls the string conversion function once, since you already know the literal string you should be comparing your variable to, you can simply define it yourself as all uppercase or all lowercase (used with strtolower); take your pick.

One of the niceties behind this concept is it is applicable in languages that don't have case insensitive functions.  Seems more universal to me; but on the other hand, having functions to do the same job is quiet convenient...

Comment: what if the search string is at the beginning of the haystack?  strpos will return 0, which would fail your comparison.  if(strpos($haystack,$needle) !== false) is a better method.

Comment: @devlincarnate agreed, updated answer.  Similarly, `>= 0` would also work instead of `!== false`

Comment: @devlincarnate that is why you should use `===` instead of `==` if string is not found it will return false and `0 !== false` is false but `0 != false` is true

Comment: @Robert:  the answer originally had  if(strpos($haystack,$needle) { //found } , which is what my comment was directed toward.  That answer has since been updated/edited.

Comment: okay I did not know that

Answer (score 0):

Convert everything to lower

```
if (in_string(strtolower($string), strtolower("stringINaSTRING"))) {
  echo "The String is in the string!";
}
```

Comment: Could be a decent answer if `in_string` were an actual function.